# MySQL Analytics Query - Improve Performance

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that holds about 8 Million Records and I need to run some analytics on it to get averages as shown in below table definition and query.  The result contains hourly analytics (avg of a parameter value) for the last 1 year data.

MySQL Server Version : 8.0.15

**Table:**

```
create table `temp_data` (
  `dateLogged`   datetime NOT NULL,
  `paramName`    varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `paramValue`   float NOT NULL,
  `sensorId`     varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
  `locationCode` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sensorId`,`paramName`,`dateLogged`),
  KEY `summary` (`locationCode`,`paramName`,`dateLogged`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

**Query:** The below query transposes row based parameters into columns and while doing so computes the average of param values

```
SELECT  dateLogged,
        ROUND(avg( ROUND(IF(paramName = 'temp1', paramValue, NULL),2) ),2) AS T1,
        ROUND(avg( ROUND(IF(paramName = 'temp2', paramValue, NULL),2) ),2) AS T2,
        ROUND(avg( ROUND(IF(paramName = 'temp3', paramValue, NULL),2) ),2) AS T3,
        ROUND(avg( ROUND(IF(paramName = 'temp4', paramValue, NULL),2) ),2) as T4
FROM temp_data where locationCode='A123' and paramName in ('temp1','temp2','temp3','temp4')
group by dateLogged order by dateLogged;
```

**Result:**

```
+---------------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| date                | T1     | T2      | T3    | T4    |
+---------------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| 2018-12-01 00:00:00 |  95.46 |   99.12 | 96.44 | 95.86 |
| 2018-12-01 01:00:00 | 100.38 |  101.09 | 99.56 | 99.70 |
| 2018-12-01 02:00:00 | 101.41 |  102.08 | 99.47 | 99.88 |
| 2018-12-01 03:00:00 |  98.79 |  100.47 | 98.59 | 99.75 |
| 2018-12-01 04:00:00 |  98.23 |  100.58 | 98.38 | 98.93 |
| 2018-12-01 05:00:00 | 101.03 |  101.80 | 99.37 | 99.88 |
   ...                   ...       ...      ...      ...
+---------------------+--------+---------+---------+-----+
```

**Problem:**

Now there are over 8 Million records in the table and the query takes approximately 35 to 40 seconds to execute.

Looking for suggestions on how to improve the query performance and hopefully, bring it down to under 10 seconds.

**Note:**

The table has data for up to 1 year and data beyond that is archived and deleted

**Result of describe:**

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | temp_data | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,summary | summary | 53      | const | 3524800 |    50.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Consider handling the transposition in application code, if appropriate

Comment: is `'temp1','temp2','temp3','temp4'` fixed values or do they change for different queries?

Comment: Your current `summary` index already gets your query about as optimal as is possible, given that you taking averages with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @danblack - the temp1 to temp4 are fixed values.  however there are other params in the table apart from these 4.

Comment: Try to execute 4 separate queries - One for each `paramName`.

Answer (score 0):

As temp1 -> temp4 are fixed we can use [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to index this:

```
alter table temp_data add p1234 bool as (paramName IN ('temp1','temp2','temp3','temp4')) NOT NULL,
ADD KEY s1234 (locationCode, p1234, paramName, paramValue, dateLogged)
```

Then change the query too:

```
SELECT  dateLogged, paramName,
        ROUND(avg( ROUND(paramValue,2) ),2)
FROM temp_data where locationCode='A123' and p1234
group by dateLogged, paramName
order by dateLogged, paramName;
```

Handle the T1 -> T4 paramName formatting in the application code

Comment: "MySQL sorts by the group by clause" - This behavior has been deprecated for years in 5.* and is removed in 8.0

Comment: Tried this against a smaller data sample (600K).  The query seems to take more time than before.  With the old way, the query took 1.98 seconds and with the new way, on the same data set,  the query took 2.49 secs. This is after altering the table as suggested.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it the sorting that is causing extra time (remove and compare), does the `EXPLAIN {query}` show use of the s1234 index, and what length of it does it use? Look at `sort_merge_passes` in the session status and consider increasing [sort_buffer_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size). This could have an effect on your original structure query too.

Comment: Sorting is not adding any more time.  In fact the stats I noted above for 600K records is without the order by clause.  Explain does indicate the use of the s1234 index.  Key length is 13 and number of rows shows 271K records.  filtered is 12.00, extra says Using where; Using temporary.

Comment: sort_buffer_size   is 262144  and sort_merge_passes is 48